# Forming an algebraic expression that is equal to its linear approximation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this problem.
The question is "Write down an algebraic expression of a function that is equal to its linear approximation
about x = 0 at two or more points other than x = 0."

I know linear approximation formula or equation is $f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) = y$,and my thinking so far is using the formula and soving for $a$, but I'm not entirely sure. What would be a reasonable approach to solving this problem?

Comment: doesn't linear function work for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  find for example a periodic function $g(x)$ with period $T$ such that $\,g(0)=g'(0)=0\,$, then consider $\,f(x) = x + g(x)\,$ at points $\,x = k\,T\,$ for integer $\,k\,$. Think trig for a simple such $\,g(x)\,$.

More generally, take any $\,g(x)\,$ such that $\,g(0)=g'(0)=0\,$ and the equation $\,g(x) = 0\,$ has two or more non-$0$ roots. Possible examples include polynomials, in case that's what `algebraic expression` was meant to indicate.